# How to auto-move emails in root folder to inbox folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook.com

We have some software which reads in and processes emails from the Inbox folder of a shared mail account.
Users manually drag emails into there from their own accounts (using Outlook).

This all works fine until some users accidentally drag the email to the ***root*** folder, not the **inbox**.

Is there a way to create an outlook rule to automatically move items in the root to the inbox?

For reference, this page is related but not the same problem:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2979451/items-placed-in-root-folder-seem-to-be-lost-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can't create such rule in Outlook because Outlook rules can process only incoming and outgoing messages, they can't work with moved/copied emails. However, you can write a VBA script that will do what you want.